# How to make a rValue reference available outside the try-block in which the RR obtains its value?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Assume that we don't want to redesign function `a_func_that_may_throw`.

```
try {
    T&& rr = a_func_that_may_throw();
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    /* Deal with the exception here. */
}
// Question: How to adapt the code above so as to have `rr` available here?
```

Sorry for not asking my question clear. The following is added to (hopefully) make the question clearer.

We can do this to pointers:

```
T *ptr = nullptr;
try {
    ptr = a_source_that_may_throw();
}
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    /* We know what happened in the try block and can do something without `ptr`. */
}
// `ptr` is available out side the try block.
```

Since C++11, we have had rValue reference on our tool shelves, which saves us from inefficiently copying huge objects returned by existing (probably bad designed) functions. Is it possible to enjoy both advantages, so we don't have to copy and can still access the returned object the same way `ptr` is used in the above code?

Thanks. m(_ _)m

Comment: If that function did throws, `rr` is undefined. Why would you want to be able to refer to it?

Comment: Other way around: Move everything that needs the reference *into* the try block.

Comment: If the function do throw, certainly we'll know and we can end the process gracefully in the catch-block.

Comment: @Mat OP is not trying to refer it if it throws he is trying to refer to it if it *didn't* throw.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: it's not clear from the question that the catch block returns (or rethrows or exits or whatever).

Comment: @Mat True, I think OPs comment about "ending the process gracefully" now makes that clear.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: feel free to edit the question then (and answer with Kerrek's comment)

Comment: @KerrekSB There might be situations where we don't want to move everything into the try block because it might confuse maintainers, including ourselves, wondering what is the purpose of this try-catch statement.

Comment: @Cody: Not *everything*, just everything that needs the reference. If that's too large to reason about, refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "deal with the exception". You could do something like this:

```
T wrap_a_func_that_may_throw() {
  try {
    return a_func_that_may_throw();
  } catch(const std::exception& e) {
    // Do cleanup, logging, etc...
    // May have to re-throw if there is
    // nothing meaningful you can return.... 
  }
  return T()  // Return empty T if possible.
}

Foo&& foo = wrap_a_func_that_may_throw();
```

Which gives you an opportunity to do any specific cleanup, logging, etc. but it may have to re-throw. As Kerrek SB says you may still need to have everything that uses the reference in a try block.

Comment: If `a_func_that_may_throw` returns by value, you'll get a lifetime issue.

Comment: @dyp for some reason I was assuming a_func_that_may_throw returns by r-value ref but you're right by value is much more likely.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason you're using an r-value reference is that you want a **non const** reference bound to the temporary, then IMHO simply don't bother. Instead use value semantics and let the compiler do the optimizations.

```
T t;
try {
    t = a_func_that_may_throw(); // Compiler can use RVO and move assign to 't'.
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    /* Deal with the exception here. */
}
// 't' has lifetime until end of scope.
```

The exception would be if `T` is not default constructible or move-assignable.

Alternatively do as mentioned by [@Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191311/how-to-make-a-rvalue-reference-available-outside-the-try-block-in-which-the-rr-o#comment41069207_26191311) in the comments, i.e. move everything into the try block.

Comment: I'd rather put this into a lambda/function to benefit from RVO: `T t = []{ try { return a_function_that_may_throw(); } catch(...) { /* ... */ } } ();`

Comment: @dyp Interesting, but what happens if the functions throws? Isn't accessing `t` later a possible UB as the lambda returns nothing (unless you return something from the `catch` block)?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to either throw or return something in the `catch` (or afterwards). The alternative is returning a `boost::optional<T>`.